# execve doesn't start the process?

Tags: c, parent-child, execve

i want to send a message in the queue by a child and print it on the father. But, father only print the process child terminated with the pid after the wait. Seem like child doesn't run and doesn't put anything on the queue. If i put i while(1) on the child for force it to not finish...the child finish the same way and i don't understand why...thanks.

master.c

```
#include "config.h"


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char * args[3] = {CHILD_NAME}; 
    int q_id,num_bytes;
    struct msgUser mt_msg;

    int sh_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,sizeof(int),0644 | IPC_CREAT);
    int *sh_value = shmat(sh_id,NULL,0);
    shmctl(sh_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);

    *sh_value = 0;

#ifndef SO_USERS_NUM
    printf("Error in main:  SO_USERS_NUM not defined");
#endif
    /* 
        Creation users, main do forks as SO_USERS_NUM is setting on confing library.
        A child do a execve to the same file .c with the required operation.
        args: array of string that contains data usefull to user
    */
    q_id = msgget(KEY_QUEUE, IPC_CREAT | 0600);
    int pid;
    for (int i = 0; i < SO_USERS_NUM; i++)
    {
        pid = fork();
        switch (pid)
        {
        case -1:
            printf("Error in main:  Fork Error");
            break;
        case 0:
            char* test;
            *sh_value = *sh_value +1;
            sprintf(test,"%d",*sh_value);
            args[1] = test;
            args[2] = NULL;          
            execve(CHILD_NAME,args,NULL);  
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
   int i = 0;
   while(i < SO_USERS_NUM){
        num_bytes = sizeof(mt_msg) - sizeof(mt_msg.mtype);

        num_bytes = msgrcv(q_id, &mt_msg, num_bytes, 3, IPC_NOWAIT);
        if (num_bytes >= 0) {
            printf("received message");
             if (num_bytes >= sizeof(mt_msg.numero))
                printf(" numero: %d", mt_msg.numero);

        printf("\n");
        } 
        pid_t pid_child = waitpid(-1,NULL,WNOHANG);
         if (pid_child > 0) {
            printf("\nProcesso figlio terminato:  %d",pid_child);
            ++i;
            }
   }
    return 0;
}
```

user.c

```
#include "config.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int q_id;
    struct msgUser my_msg;
    printf("\n user id: %s \n",argv[1]);
    q_id = msgget(KEY_QUEUE, IPC_CREAT | 0600);
    
    my_msg.mtype = 3;
    my_msg.numero = 33;
    int num_bytes = sizeof(my_msg) - sizeof(my_msg.mtype);
    msgsnd(q_id, &my_msg, num_bytes, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

config.h:

```
struct msgUser {
    long mtype;             /* message type, must be > 0 */
    int numero;
};
/*
    KEY_QUEUE define the start key for the master process.
    Children nodes will increase this value to create owner's queue
*/
#define KEY_QUEUE 0x200800                     
/*
   CHILD_NAME name of users's code lauched by execve
*/
#define CHILD_NAME "user"
/*
   SO_USERS_NUM define the maximum number of users
*/
#define SO_USERS_NUM 3
```

Comment: Print something after `execve`. If you see it printed, `execve` has failed.

Answer (score 0):

Process executed by execve is not a child process of your parent. As you use wait execve will send SIGTRAP to your child which will terminate it.

Also, your program won't work, because execve detaches from shared memory.